# How to solve $(x-2)f(y)+f(y+2f(x)) = f(x + yf(x))$?

Tags: functional-equations

I'm trying to solve this task:

> Find all functions $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ that satisfy: $(x-2)f(y)+f(y+2f(x)) = f(x + yf(x))$

I plugged in $x=2$:

$f(y + 2f(2)) = f(2 + yf(2))$

If I assume that values are equal:

$y + 2f(2) = 2 + yf(2)$

Then I get:

$f(2) = 1$

So then I randomly checked $f(x) = x - 1$ and it turned out to be a solution.

I then tried some other things but didn't really get anything.

Could somebody please give a hint as to how to find other solutions?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3952851/solutions-to-the-functional-equation-x-2-f-y-f-big-y-2-f-x?noredirect=1)

Comment: What is the source of this problem?

Comment: I got it from my maths teacher

Comment: [Approach Zero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24(x-2)f(y)%2Bf(y%2B2f(x))%20%3D%20f(x%20%2B%20yf(x))%24&p=1) found many solutions to that problem.

Comment: @Gonçalo wow, thanks!

Comment: You can assume that the values are equal since for $y=0$ you get a functional equation which implies that $f$ is injective (unless $f(0)=0$ which implies $f=0$).